# Adicionar campo Identity em tabela já preenchida

Tags: sql-server

Como faço para resolver a situação abaixo:

Tenho uma tabela onde os dados foram inseridos na seguinte ordem:

```
INSERT INTO teste(Nome) VALUES('C')
INSERT INTO teste(Nome) VALUES('D')
INSERT INTO teste(Nome) VALUES('B')
INSERT INTO teste(Nome) VALUES('A')
```

Nessa tabela já preenchida farei a criação de um campo *Identity alfanumérico* que não tem. Quando criar essa coluna, o próprio SQL vai preencher a coluna alfanumérica. Será que ele vai numerar conforme a ordem que foi inserido ou vai pegar ordem aleatória para aplicar o *Identity*?

Precisava desse resultado:

> ```
> ID      Nome
> 1        C
> 2        D
> 3        B
> 4        A
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso sim, vai usar como parâmetro a ordem a qual foi inserida. É usado o index da tabela para definir essa ordem.

[image: Print do teste]

Comment: Agradeço pelos esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 1):

> Será que ele vai numerar conforme a ordem que foi inserido ou vai pegar ordem aleatória para aplicar o Identity?

No SQL Server uma tabela é um conjunto de dados sem qualquer ordem. Mesmo que exista uma coluna com uma suposta sequência, ainda assim é um conjunto de dados sem ordem. Somente ao listar o conteúdo é que se pode solicitar que essa ordem seja executada conforme o conteúdo de coluna(s).

A existência de índice também não significa que o SELECT retornará o resultado ordenado pelo índice. Aliás, isto está bem claro na documentação da cláusula [ORDER BY](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql): *The order in which rows are returned in a result set are not guaranteed unless an ORDER BY clause is specified*.

Na documentação de [tabelas Heap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/heaps-tables-without-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) consta o seguinte trecho: *Data is stored in the heap without specifying an order. Usually data is initially stored in the order in which is the rows are inserted into the table, but the Database Engine can move data around in the heap to store the rows efficiently; so the data order cannot be predicted*.

Ou seja, **não se pode afirmar** que a numeração na coluna identity será na mesma sequência em que as linhas foram incluídas.

Comment: Boa resposta, bem embasada